# Display Data for Current Session Only

Tags: pine-script

I've been coding an indicator to display daily and previous day OHLC values. I know it's been done a million times been done a million times before but I wanted to make a version that's unobtrusive and easy to follow. I want to make a switch to give the option to display data for the current session only or for each trading session. Something like this:

```
showCurrent = input(true, title='Display current period only')
```

I also found a snippet of code which displays data fro the current trading day only

```
currentOnly = false

if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    currentOnly := true
```

I'd like to know how to combine them so that when showCurrent == true, yesterday's and today's levels are displayed on the current session only

This is what the code looks like. Very basic:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Daily OHLC', overlay=true)


showCurrent = input(true, title='Display current period only')
showOpen = input(true, title='Daily open')
showPrevClose = input(true, title='Previous day close')
showHiLo = input(true, title='Daily high & low')
showPrevHiLo = input(false, title='Previous day high & low')


currentOnly = false

if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    currentOnly := true


dailyOpen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dailyHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dailyLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)


openColour = dailyOpen != dailyOpen[1] ? na : close < dailyOpen ? #F23645 : #4CAF50
prevCloseColour = prevClose != prevClose[1] ? na : close < prevClose ? #F23645 : #4CAF50
highColour = dailyHigh != dailyHigh[1] ? na : #4CAF50
lowColour = dailyLow != dailyLow[1] ? na : #F23645


plot(timeframe.multiplier < 60 ? showOpen and dailyOpen ? dailyOpen : na : na, title='Daily Open', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=openColour, transp=20)
plot(timeframe.multiplier < 60 ? showPrevClose and prevClose ? prevClose : na : na, title='Previous Day Close', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=prevCloseColour, transp=60)
plot(timeframe.multiplier < 60 ? showHiLo and dailyHigh ? dailyHigh : na : na, title='Daily High', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=highColour, transp=20)
plot(timeframe.multiplier < 60 ? showHiLo and dailyLow ? dailyLow : na : na, title='Daily Low', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=lowColour, transp=20)
plot(timeframe.multiplier < 60 ? showPrevHiLo and prevHigh ? prevHigh : na : na, title='Previous Day High', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=highColour, transp=20)
plot(timeframe.multiplier < 60 ? showPrevHiLo and prevLow ? prevLow : na : na, title='Previous Day Low', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=lowColour, transp=20)
```

[image: Current session only]

I want to be able to switch between this and this

[image: Past sessions included]

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you intended.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Daily OHLC', overlay=true)

showCurrent     = input.bool(true,  title='Display current period only')
showOpen        = input.bool(true,  title='Daily open')
showPrevClose   = input.bool(true,  title='Previous day close')
showHiLo        = input.bool(true,  title='Daily high & low')
showPrevHiLo    = input.bool(false, title='Previous day high & low')

[dailyOpen, prevClose, dailyHigh, dailyLow, prevHigh, prevLow] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [open, close[1], high, low, high[1], low[1]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

openColour      = color.new(dailyOpen != dailyOpen[1] ? na : close < dailyOpen ? #F23645 : #4CAF50, 20)
prevCloseColour = color.new(prevClose != prevClose[1] ? na : close < prevClose ? #F23645 : #4CAF50, 60)
highColour      = color.new(dailyHigh != dailyHigh[1] ? na : #4CAF50,                               20)
lowColour       = color.new(dailyLow != dailyLow[1]   ? na : #F23645,                               20)

isToday = year(timenow) == year and month(timenow) == month and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth
canShow = timeframe.multiplier < 60 and isToday or not showCurrent

plot(canShow and showOpen and dailyOpen      ? dailyOpen : na, title='Daily Open',          style=plot.style_line,    linewidth=1, color=openColour)
plot(canShow and showPrevClose and prevClose ? prevClose : na, title='Previous Day Close',  style=plot.style_line,    linewidth=1, color=prevCloseColour)
plot(canShow and showHiLo and dailyHigh      ? dailyHigh : na, title='Daily High',          style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=highColour)
plot(canShow and showHiLo and dailyLow       ? dailyLow  : na, title='Daily Low',           style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=lowColour)
plot(canShow and showPrevHiLo and prevHigh   ? prevHigh  : na, title='Previous Day High',   style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=highColour)
plot(canShow and showPrevHiLo and prevLow    ? prevLow   : na, title='Previous Day Low',    style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=lowColour)
```